# How to exclude subdomains from https rewriting on nignx?

Tags: ssl, nginx, passenger, lets-encrypt

I have recently installed LetsEncrypt SSL certificate which works great on my primary domain, but I have also other subdomains which are set up as virtual hosts. However, all traffic to subdomain is now redirected to https, which leads to browsers complain about privacy.

My primary domain nginx configuration looks like:

```
server {                                                                                                              │
        listen 80;                                                                                                    │
        server_name domain.com www.domain.com;                                                                          │
        return 301 https://$server_name$request_uri;                                                                  │
}                                                                                                                     │
                                                                                                                      │
server {                                                                                                              │
        # Basic configuration                                                                                         │
        listen 443 ssl;                                                                                               │
        server_name domain.com www.domain.com;                                                                      │
        passenger_enabled on;                                                                                         │
        passenger_app_env development;                                                                                │
        root /home/user/path_to_app/public;                                                                       │
                                                                                                                      │
        # Required for LetsEncryptSSL certificate                                                                     │
        location ~ /.well-known {                                                                                     │
                        allow all;                                                                                    │
        }                                                                                                             │
                                                                                                                      │
        # Include SSL config                                                                                          │
        include snippets/ssl-domain.com.conf;                                                                        │
        include snippets/ssl-params.conf;                                                                             │
}
```

And my subdomain config is like this:

```
server {                                                                                                              │
        #listen 80 default_server;                                                                                    │
        server_name app1.domain.com;                                                                                 │
        passenger_enabled on;                                                                                         │
        passenger_app_env development;                                                                                │
        root /home/app1/app1/public;                                                                                  │
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I think the only chance to do it is to define `server_name` as regex in the first parenthesis.
That is, something like  this

```
server {                                                                                                             
        listen 80;                                                               
        server_name ^(www\.domain\.com|domain\.com)$;
        return 301 https://$server_name$request_uri;
        }
```

http://nginx.org/en/docs/http/server_names.html